# Default path for MSDN Reports Services /ReportServer and /Reports virtual directories

Tags: reporting-services, virtual-directory

I'm trying to use MSDN Reports Services 2005, but I'm realising that I broke the installation, so I'm trying to fix it without having to rebuild it entirely.  (Though I'm becoming more tempted the longer this goes on.)  Unfortunately, all the documentation assumes you haven't done something stupid. ;)

Amongst the things I've broken in the process is that I've lost the IIS virtual directories that used to point to the server and reports directories (/ReportServer, /Reports), and I can't remember which directory they used to point to.  I'm guessing something like "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.3\Reporting Services\ReportManager", but all the ones I've tried thus far don't seem to have been right.

As far as I remember, it was an installation where I installed with the default settings everywhere (e.g. the main app is located in C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server).  It's the Developer edition of MSSQL Server, if that makes a difference.

So, can someone dig around in their (functional) copy and find this out for me? :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After several hours of headaches, I have established the addresses to be:

Reports: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.3\Reporting Services\ReportManager

ReportServer: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.3\Reporting Services\ReportServer

Of course, you need all the file associations in place, and the rest, as well.  Sigh.

Comment: `MSSQL.3` is the name of your SQL instance, so it's unlikely this folder will actually be in this exact path. Just info for anyone who may not know this.